# Existence of the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (x+\sqrt x)}{\cos(x-\sqrt x)} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Can anyone help me in evaluating the following integral :
$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (x+\sqrt x)}{\cos(x-\sqrt x)} dx$. I tried doing this by substitution but didn't work. Also  by parts looks cumbersome.

Comment: It looks horrific, try contour integration to avoid actually evaluating the integral.

Comment: I agree with orion. Did you encounter this integral somewhere? Do you have *any* reason to believe the integral is doable?

Comment: As said in previous comments, evaluating the integral looks to be a potential nightmare. If contour integration does not work, use numerical methods.

Comment: I found this in a paper while I was searching for something else in my study cupboard. I don't know whether it exists or not. But nevertheless I tried various methods but none worked. May be I should try it numerically.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the numerator and denominator using angle addition formulas for the sine and cosine function, and then employing [Fresnel integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)?

Comment: I don't think this converges on $(0, \pi)$. It's a $\tan$ function on it's period...

Comment: Wolframalpha gives the value $ -0.851945$. So apparently it converges. The number of digits is too short to guess on the exact number (ISC gives a lot of possibilities)

Comment: Mathematica gives $-0.851945423233506$. No result from ISC or Wolframalpha